# Simple Injector "instance is requested outside the context of an active (Async Scoped) scope" when using `ContinueWith`

Tags: c#, multithreading, async-await, simple-injector

I have a block of code that throws:

> is registered using the 'Async Scoped' lifestyle, but the instance is requested outside the context of an active (Async Scoped) scope`

1. The above is thrown when I use `return` for the `Task` (at higher volumes, but ok at lower processing volumes)
2. It however works OK regardless of thru-put request volume when I `await` the `Task`, Simple Injector does not throw.

I appreciate this may be more of a async focused question as opposed to Simple Injector, but any insights why replacing `return` with `await` *resolves* this?

Thanks in advance, I am concerned whilst "working" using `await` is it potentially hiding a larger issue.

**Background:**

I have the following loop that deques items (tasks to be dispatched) by a worker:

```cs
void Loop()
{
    while (cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested == false)
    {
        item = await this.queue.Reader.ReadAsync(cancellationToken);
        
        await DispatchItemAsync(item, (item, dispatcher) =>
        {
            return dispatcher
                .SendAsync(((ISendItem)item).GetHandler, item.Message, item.CancellationToken)
                .ContinueWith(t => item.TaskCompletionSourceWrapper.SetResult(t.Result), TaskContinuationOptions.RunContinuationsAsynchronously);
        });
    }
}
```

The `DispatchItemAsync` from the above loop is below:

```cs
protected override async Task DispatchItemAsync(
    IQueueItem item, Func<IQueueItem, IThreadStrategy, Task> dispatchFunc)
{
    // cast the passed item from channel queue
    var queueItemWithStack = item as IQueueItemWithStack;

    using (AsyncScopedLifestyle.BeginScope(this.container))
    {
        var dispatcher = container.GetInstance<InParallel>();
        // the above is an interface of delegates that is used to call functions
        
        // return throws SimpleInjector outside of scope exception (intermittent,
        // always for high request volume)
        return dispatchFunc(queueItemWithStack, dispatcher);

        // using await no exception is thrown
        // await dispatchFunc(queueItemWithStack, dispatcher);
    }
}
```

With `InParallel` containing the function which is called by the `dispatchFunc` line, the below is (eventually via a chain) called:

```cs
public Task<object> SendAsync(
    Func<SendFunction> getHandler,
    object request,
    CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
{
    return this
        .inCaller
        .SendAsync(getHandler, request, cancellationToken)
        .ContinueWith(t =>
        { 
            // snip some code
            // the below throws if DispatchItemAsync call us with return
            // but is OK if DispatchItemAsync called us with await instead
            return t.Result;
        });
}
```

The exception occurs on the above `ContinueWith` when the `t.Result` is accessed:

> CommandHandler is registered using the 'Async Scoped' lifestyle, but the instance is requested outside the context of an active (Async Scoped) scope. Please see https://simpleinjector.org/scoped for more information about how apply lifestyles and manage scopes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By *not* awaiting a `Task`, you are executing the `Task` *in parallel* with the primary operation. Parallel means the code becomes multi threaded.

This means that the original `Scope` will likely get disposed before the `Task` finished executing. This causes the exception you are experiencing. But in other cases, the `Scope` might get disposed of during the execution of the `Task`. This will cause objects getting disposed of while the `Task` is running. This can cause weird multi-threading issues.

What this means is that, in your case, you should *absolutely* await the `Task` that is returned from `dispatchFunc`.